# SQL Server : the multipart identifier could not be bound in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this problem where I am getting a multipart identifier error. I am just asking for an explanation more than a solution. I was able to get query to work but I am still not understanding the problem. Below are three queries and the first and third work fine but I do not understand why the second one is throwing the error:

> The multi-part identifier "[TableName].[FieldName]" could not be bound.

Works:

```
select [SchemaName].[TableName].[FieldName] 
from [SchemaName].[TableName]
```

Throws error:

```
select [TableName].[FieldName] 
from [SchemaName].[TableName]
```

Works:

```
select [FieldName] 
from [SchemaName].[TableName]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think your examples are correct. You can't select from a field. More likely your first and third examples are ...from [SchemaName].[TableOrViewOrUDFFunctionName]. In any case you can't select from a field. You select a field from a table.

Comment: None of those should work if `FieldName` truly is a field on a table. You can only select `FROM` a table, view, derived table, or table variable. It should not be possible to select from a field at all.

Comment: sorry it was supposed to read [SchemaName].[TableName] in the from clause

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  It works for me in SQL 2008 R2.  You can check your version by running `Select @@Version`

Comment: This works for me as well against different databases. My question is what would cause this kind of problem in one db as opposed to another?

Comment: is it really that simple of a query, or are there other joins involved?

Comment: The original problem was joins and such however I broke it down to where I identified the problem using these three queries which are indeed as simple as they appear

Answer (score 1):

Its should be

```
select [FieldName] from [SchemaName].[TableName]
```

OR

```
select [FieldName] from [DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName]
```

OR

```
select [TableName].[FieldName] from [DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName]
```

OR

```
select [SchemaName].[TableName].[FieldName] from [DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName]
```

OR

```
select [DataBaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName].[FieldName] from [DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName]
```

But it will never be

```
SELECT <Any-of-The-Above> FROM [TableName].[FieldName] --<-- Cant have Field name here
```

Comment: For anyone that views this question now and is confused by this answer... This is the correct answer for the original question, but the original question had a typo in it which has now been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely your issue is that you are logged in using a database user whose default schema is different than the schema of the table from which you are selecting (or has no default schema).

For example: Say you have 2 schemas in your database, `dbo` and `reports`. Your database user was setup with a default schema of `dbo`.  If you have a table in a `reports` schema `reports.table1`, and there is not a synonym in the `dbo` schema for `dbo.table1` that points to `reports.table1`, then you will get this error if you do not specify the schema when selecting the field name.

**NOTE:** this appears to work in SQL 2008 R2, but when I tested in SQL 2005 then I received the error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The multi-part identifier
>   "TestTable.TestField" could not be bound.

You can check the default schema for your user by using this query:

```
select p.name, p.default_schema_name 
from sys.database_principals p 
order by p.name
```

A way to get around this is by using table alias' in your query, or to specify the full path to the table as you mentioned in OP.

```
select t.[FieldName] 
from [SchemaName].[TableName] as t
```

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my own question the compatibility level for the database I was using was set to 80. I changed it to 100 and the issue was resolved. Thanks all for your feedback.